# Can I bind results of a Dapper query to something other than IEnumerabe<T> without breaking it?

Tags: c#, .net, dapper

What type can I use to declare a variable of the same type that Dapper Query returns, such that it still streams vs. buffers and I can access the variable from an external block?

For instance, I have (assuming conn is the SqlConnection):

```
try
{
    var queryResults = await conn.QueryAsync<QueryResultType>(@"BLA BLA SQL", params);
} 
catch (Exception e) 
{
    //bla bla bla C#
}
```

Now what I want to do, is just declare queryResults outside the try-catch so I can use it in ANOTHER, separate try-catch...

```
IEnumerable<QueryResultType> queryResults;
try
{
    queryResults = await conn.QueryAsync<QueryResultType>(@"BLA BLA SQL", params);
} 
catch (Exception e) 
{
    //bla bla bla C#
}

try
{
    foreach(var qr in queryResults) 
    {
        // whatever logic
    }
} 
catch (Exception e) 
{
    //bla bla bla C#
}
```

Now clearly I cannot instantiate IEnumerable, but I'm also trying to preserve the STREAMING behavior of Dapper (buffered: false), so I didn't think I could just use a List as won't that cause it to treat the query as buffered?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What is wrong with `IEnumerable<T>`? that should work, no? also: note that `IEnumerable<T>` doesn't always play nicely with async - I really want them to add async-enumerables! I can't 100% remember whether `buffered:false` and `async` respect streaming, but I can probably check if you really need. It looks like the only real problem in the code shown is "definite assignment", but you can fix that by defaulting it to `null` and just checking the local for `null` before iterating it. Or just set `queryResults = Array.Empty<T>();` in the first `catch`

Comment: You don't need to instantiate it; your code will work fine.

Comment: `what can I use instead of IEnumberable<QueryResultType> queryResults` Why do you want something **instead of**? Just use `IEnumerable<QueryResultType>`.

Comment: @mjwillis by golly you are right.... thank you

Answer (score -1):

I had mistakenly thought I was prohibited from declaring IEnumerable. My apologies, move along, nothing to see here.